# How to send multiple requests at once ReactPHP?

Tags: php, asynchronous, guzzle, reactphp

I am using guzzle to send some requests:

```
$response = $this->client->request(new SomeObject());
```

using the class below

```
...
public function request(Request $request)
{
    return $this->requestAsync($request)->wait();
}

// Here I'm using Guzzle Async, but I can remove that is needed
public function requestAsync(Request $request)
{
    $promise = $this->http->requestAsync($request->getMethod(), $request->getUri());

    $promise = $promise->then(
        function (ResponseInterface $response) use ($request) {
            return $response;
        }
    );

    return $promise;
}
...
```

I would like to use ReactPHP to send multiple requests at once in a foreach loop:

```
$requests = [];
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $requests[] = $this->client->request(new SomeObject());
}

// pass $requests to ReactPHP here and wait on the response
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't need ReactPHP to use parallel HTTP requests with Guzzle. Guzzle itself provides this feature (if you use cURL handler, which is the default).

For example:

```
$promises = [];
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $promises[] = $guzzleClient->getAsync(/* some URL */);
}

// Combine all promises
$combinedPromise = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\all($promises)

// And wait for them to finish (all requests are executed in parallel)
$responses = $combinedPromise->wait();
```

If you still want to use Guzzle with ReactPHP event loop, then, unfortunately, there are no straightforward solution. You cat take a look at https://github.com/productsupcom/guzzle-react-bridge (I'm the developer, so feel free to ask questions).

Comment: Yeah, I am using Guzzle Async now. It's working great. I just wanted to try ReactPHP and see if I gain any speed. Do you have an example using `guzzle-react-bridge` with something similar to my scenario?

Comment: I will search for an example, but it would not lead to speed gain, unfortunately. The `guzzle-react-bridge` provides interoperability, but doesn't replace Guzzle's cURL handler with the ReactPHP.